# при запуске кода выдаёт ошибку KeyError: 'screen_name'

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
тут показано что консоль выдаёт ошибку KeyError: 'screen_name'
подскажите пожалуйста с чем это связано?

код на python если что

Comment: у переменной нет индекса или ключа screen_name

Comment: Полную ошибку рекомендуется помещать. И в виде текста, а не копии экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно официальной документации Python 3, ошибка KeyError возникает, когда  ключ набора (словаря) не найден в наборе существующих ключей.

Эта ошибка встречается, когда мы пытаемся получить или удалить значение ключа из словаря, и этот ключ не существует в словаре.

```
>>> test = dict()
>>> test["key1"] = "value1"
>>> print(a["key2"])
>>> print(test["key2"]) // ключ  key2 мы не создавали, то есть получим закономерную ошибку KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'key2'
```

То есть в твоем случае ты пытаешься обратиться к ключу screen_name у своего словаря, который ранее не объявил. Если пришлешь полный код - скажем поточнее где что дописать.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я уже решил проблему